# Jenkins API: EnvVars.overrideAll not overriding existing environment variables in Pipeline job.

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to set Jenkins environment variables at runtime via the EnvironmentContributor.buildEnvironmentFor() method. Suppose I set an environment variable named "existingKey" with value "oldValue" in the Jenkins configure page. If I set existingKey to any other value by using EnvVars.overrideAll it doesn't take. New key/value pairs persist. Here's my code:

```
@Extension
public class MyEnvironmentContributor extends EnvironmentContributor {
    Logger log...

    @Override
    public void buildEnvironmentFor(@Nonnull Job j, @Nonnull EnvVars envs, @Nonnull TaskListener listener) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        log.fine("pre: existingKey="+envs.get("existingKey"));

        HashMap<String, String> newEnvVars = new HashMap<String, String>();
        newEnvVars.put("newKey", "newValue");
        newEnvVars.put("existingKey","newValue");
        envs.overrideAll(newEnvVars);

        log.fine("post: existingKey="+envs.get("existingKey"));
    }
}
```

I have tested the above with both buildEnvironmentFor(Job,...) and buildEnvironmentFor(Run,...) with the same result. I have also tried EnvVar.override() and envVar.overrideExpandingAll(), none seem to work.

I have also extended RunListener, which allows me to monitor if my env variables get set.

```
@Extension
public class MyRunListener extends RunListener<Run> {
    Logger log.....

    public MyRunListener(){
        //lazy loaded class
    }

    @Override
    public void onStarted(final Run run, final TaskListener listener) {
        log.fine("Build Started: " + run.getUrl() + ", " + run.getDisplayName());
        try{
            EnvVars env = run.getEnvironment(listener);
            for (Entry<String, String> entry : env.entrySet()) {
                log.fine(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
            }
        }catch(){//trivial}
    }
}
```

The resulting logs look like this:

```
Build Started: job/Test/job/EnvTest/20/, #20
pre: existingKey=oldValue
post: existingKey=newValue
newKey=newValue
existingKey=oldValue
```

I am also printing out the env in my build container and it shows the same pattern. Any ideas how to actually override existing variables and not just set new ones?

Comment: I have a suspicion that this is because I am using a Pipeline job, and this is a known bug/feature of jenkins and pipeline jobs right now. (https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/271)

Comment: I think this is my answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jenkinsci-dev/FM_Nx_K_v9g/4BzWXd3cAgAJ "And yes `env` caches variables after first use, to avoid performance 
problems. There is not currently any provision to rerun 
`EnvironmentContributor`s, nor any API in Jenkins for such 
contributors to indicate that their result might have changed since 
the last call. "

Answer (score 0):

Since, [EnvVars](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/EnvVars.html) extends `TreeMap`, before inserting `existingKey` you can remove it i.e.

```
log.fine("pre: existingKey="+envs.get("existingKey"));

envs.remove("existingKey");
newEnvVars.put("newKey", "newValue");
newEnvVars.put("existingKey","newValue");
envs.overrideAll(newEnvVars);    

log.fine("post: existingKey="+envs.get("existingKey"));
```

Comment: I edited your code to use the overrideAll method. Removing the elements from envs before calling overrideAll did not fix the issue. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is not possible.

> And yes `env` caches variables after first use, to avoid performance 
>   problems. There is not currently any provision to rerun 
>   `EnvironmentContributor`s, nor any API in Jenkins for such 
>   contributors to indicate that their result might have changed since 
>   the last call. 
>   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jenkinsci-dev/FM_Nx_K_v9g/4BzWXd3cAgAJ