# Jenkins : how to delete delete var

Tags: jenkins, groovy, var

I'm using `envVars.put("foo", "foo")` in order to set var in Jenkins. 
I'm looking for how to remove foo var when job is completed ?

Answer (score 1):

You could start with:

```
envVars.put("foo", "")
```

Setting `foo` to an empty value should be enough to make sure the environment variable does not persists for subsequent jobs.
(But [not for the current job though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48527669/6309))

Comment: Actually, I would like to definitely delete var.

Comment: On a Windows node, for instance, that is actually how you delete an environment variable: by setting it up to an empty value. Give it a try and see if the environment variable is still listed on the next job execution.

Comment: i tried envVars.remove("foo"), but it doesn't work, your code is working. thanks